# How to use child attributes in a inherited method

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, parent-child

I'm making a basic game and want to create a "Character" parent class that will be a parent to both NPCs and the player character. What I'm struggling with is when I call an inherited method I want to be able to use a attribute  that is assigned in the child. To put it into context I want to write a draw function that I can call from the main program that passes the Graphics object to be draw to, I have a method here that worked while I was testing it by putting it directly into the player character class:

```
public void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, coords[0], coords[1]);
        }
```

So I have this in the parent class but both the image and coords are assigned in the child class. I can define the type of variable the will be in the parent but it still doesnt recognise that the have been defined.

I am calling it as `player.Draw(g)` (where player is an instance of the child class) but i either get "image is null" or "image is not defined" depending on whether I've put the `Bitmap image;` at the top or not. The image is definalty defined in the child class.

TLDR: how do I get the parent class to reference something defined in a child class when calling the method from that child class.

Comment: This is wrong logic, you can not call something from child class in parent class because your parent class wouldn't know a type or properties or methods of child class. But, other way is to add another argument to your function and pass there something from child class

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [mcve] showing what you're trying to do - just show us a placeholder `// here is my problem`` for the bit of code you're stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot of a stab in the dark with the info, but if you can make your Character class abstract, maybe something like this will help you.

Essentially the implementation of Draw lives with the Character base class (abstract) and the specializations or Image and Coordinates live with the NPC and Player classes. Guessing that is what you were looking for.

```
void Main()
{
    var player = new Player();
    var npc = new NPC();

    var characters = new List<Character>(new Character[] { player, npc});

    foreach (var character in characters)
    {
        character.Draw();
    }
}

abstract class Character
{
    public abstract string Image { get; }

    public abstract string Coordinate { get; }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Drawing Image {Image} at Coordinate {Coordinate}");
    }
}

class NPC : Character
{
    public override string Image => "NPC IMAGE";

    public override string Coordinate => "NPC Coordinate";
}

class Player : Character
{
    public override string Image => "PLAYER IMAGE";

    public override string Coordinate => "PLAYER Coordinate";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent classes cannot call methods from child classes. When working with Inheritance you want to define all the logic that is common at the top level (parent).

Child classes that inherit from a parent class, can then call the methods of their parents. It always flows from the top down. With every child class getting more specific in terms of functionality.

I would strongly suggest that you do some research into inheritance for object oriented programming before moving forward as you are struggling with some fundamentals here.

This would be a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance